# Wired GFCI vs. 40v 5a battery use near spa

Tags: safety

My wife has recently taken to running a cord out near our pool to watch TV.  She's very careful, but I was thinking of doing what I can to make it safer, since the outlet in question is NOT a GFCI outlet (It's a standard US 110v outlet).

One obvious solution is an inline GFCI.

The other more expensive idea that occurred to me is using a 5ah 40v lithium battery that I can purchase a 300w inverter for.

My guess here is that if the wired TV were to go into the water, a GFCI would be better than nothing, but unsafe...whereas the battery would be practically speaking likely to be completely safe.  Can anyone enlighten me as to which approach would be the safest, and if either or both is actually "safe"?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think an inverter would be an safer. I would make a more permanent installation for everything before an inverter.

Comment: This is probably a better question for diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: A cord that doesn't allow the TV to reach any splashes is safer for the TV.  Instructing  her only to use the remote is safest for her and don't try to watch it on an air mattress like  some crazy Russians did on Youtube. But you are more likely to feel a few milliamps with a laptop being charged and bare feet on the back lawn thru your bare knees or wrist to the case due to the RF EMI filter caps. (considered safe 2.5mA leakage max)

Comment: You could replace the outlet she uses with a GFCI type.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - she keeps the TV at least 2 feet from the water and uses the remote.  The concern would be an unlikely stumble or somesuch when adjusting the position of the TV resulting in it going into the pool/hot tub while plugged in.

Comment: Shorten the cable with tie wraps (ha)but replacing the outlet with a GFCI is a no brainer for anyone handy with wiring. or hire an electrician to install it. or bribe an engineer with an adult beverage

Comment: I would replace the outlet she is using with a GFCI outlet. They are only around $20 USD where I live, and not difficult to install. Modern electric code requires all household outlets to have GFCI protection (at least). Note that modern houses often use GFCI breakers for outlet circuits in the house. If your house has this, then every outlet is GFCI protected by the circuit breaker. AFCI may now be required by the code. I am not up-to-date on electrical code issues.

Comment: GFCI is a good idea, but if it's only a TV, consider getting a low-voltage battery television.   It's totally isolated from ground, so there's no danger of a grounded wet spot completing a circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess here is that if the wired TV were to go into the water, a GFCI would be better than nothing, but unsafe...whereas the battery would be practically speaking likely to be completely safe.

120v from an inverter is still 120v.  If that goes into the pool, you could be injured or killed.  Nothing about that is safe.

The whole idea of a GFCI is that if you drop something into a body of water, the voltage is interrupted once a few mA starts to flow, generally fast enough that you won't be injured.

Comment: Really glad I know that my intuition about electricity is usually wrong and asked.  Thanks!